# Формирование словаря по value

Tags: python

Нужна помощь, из списка получить словарь, который бы из хобби человека вывел имена.

```
data: str -> dict:
```

**Например,**

```
Маша:футбол, Артур:хоккей, Миша:футбол, Моника:теннис, Ира:теннис.
```

Из этого он должен делать dict:

```
{хоккей: [Артур], теннис: [Моника, Ира], футбол: [Маша, Миша]}
```

```
result = {}
sort_dictionary = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in dict.items()} 
for line in data.split('\n'):
    name, hobby = line.split(":")
    result.setdefault(hobby, []).append(name)
    result = sort_dictionary(result)
return result
```

В это коде так же необходимо сделать так, чтобы повторений имён не было в value.

Comment: Вам для начала нужен split, остальное вы уже должны знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле после:

```
name,hobby=line.split(":")

result.setdefault(hobby,[]).append(name)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]